# Physics Word Problem Concerning Finding Power

Tags: calculus, physics

A twin engine jet aircraft is climbing at a 10 degree angle at 260 ft/s. The thrust developed by a jet engine is 1000 lb. The power developed by the aircraft is  ______

(2000 lb)* (260 ft/s) =

Would the above equation the appropriate way to find the final answer?

Comment: Do you think $260=269$? If not, some explanation would be nice.

Comment: Sorry typo error, it meant to say 2000 lb * 260 ft/s =

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You have the correct units, since power is work per unit time. But work is force in the direction of travel: $W=\textbf{F}\cdot \textbf{d}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the 260 ft/sec is vertical speed, the power lifting the plane is indeed $2000 \cdot 260$ ft-lb/sec.  If $260$ ft/sec is the speed of flight (which seems more reasonable to me) you need to multiply by an appropriate trig function to get the vertical speed.  Both of these ignore the power needed to overcome drag.